# yahoo finance api, get the currency of stock exchange

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

Is it possible with yahoo to get the currency of an exchange?

f.eks Apple is on NSM exchange. And I'd like to retrieve which currency NSM is traded with.

```
url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+PNDORA.CO&f=x"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(ftpstream, 'utf-8'))

for line in csvfile:
    print(line)
```

I used above code to get the exchange of the stock by symbol.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @tristan I've updated it. But it was merely a question wether it existed.

Comment: A question if the currency just exists would (rightfully) closed on SO as off-topic.  Take a look at the data and if it's in the CSV.  If not, getting the currency is a question for Yahoo.

Comment: @tristan It's not in the csv. The only thing in it is the Stock Exchange. I'm not asking if the currency exist. But if there's an API or with Yahoo API, some way to get the currency of a stock exchange

Comment: I think this question is off-topic per [the site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Sorry, but this is to broad.  I'd try Yahoo!'s help/support for more information.